# On the subring $k + Y k [X,Y]$ of the polynomial ring $k[X,Y]$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension, integral-extensions

Let $k$ be a field. Let $B = k[X,Y]$ and $A=k + YB$. So we have the ring extension $ A \subseteq B$. Now I can show that the [conductor ideal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductor_(ring_theory)) of $A$ in $B$ is $YB$. So if $Q(A), Q(B)$ are the fraction fields of $A,B$ respectively , then $ A \subseteq B \subseteq Q (A) \subseteq Q(B)$. I am trying to show the following facts about $A$ and $B$:

1) $A$ is normal domain, i.e., $A$ is integrally closed in $Q(A)$.

2) The ideal $YB$ in $A$ has height 2.

3) $ \sqrt {YA}=YB$

I haven't been able to prove any of the four facts fully. For (1) I can see that if $g \in Q(A)$ is integral over $A$, then $g$ is integral over the UFD $B$, so $g \in B$, but I am unable to conclude $g \in A$. For (2), the only thing I can see is that $YB = YB \cap A$ is prime ideal in $A$. I have no idea for (3).

Please help for proving the facts. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE ON (1) : Let $g(X,Y) \in B$ be integral over $A$. Now any element $f(X,Y) \in A$ is of the form $a + Y h (X,Y)$ where $a=f(X,0) \in k$. So writing a monic equation for $g$ with coefficients in $A$ and putting $Y=0$ , we see that $g(X,0)$ is constant . Thus $g(X,Y) \in A$ so we are done. I hope this proof is correct.

Comment: For $2)$, it seems like $xB \cap A$ is a prime ideal containing $xy$, not containing $y$. So $0 \subset xB \cap A \subset yB \cap B$ is a saturated chain of prime ideals of length $2$.

Comment: @Youngsu : it would be helpful if you add proofs to your claims and may be write it as a partial answer ...

Comment: Hi misao, $y$ is not in $xB \cap A$ since $y$ is not in $xB$, and a contraction of a prime ideal is prime. The ideal $yB$ is prime in $A$ as it is maximal in $A$.

Comment: @Youngsu : thanks ..  I understand that ... and why can't we have a chain of more than two prime ideals below $YB \cap A$ ?

Comment: Hi again, I believe that it follows from a theorem of Gilmer as the quotient rings of A and B are the same. (This shows that the Krull dimensions of A and B are equal.) Look at Prop 3.3 in "Robert Gilmer's work on semigroup rings" by D. Anderson, MR2265799.